# Firefox has stopped working for Selenium 2.45

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven-3

I have been getting this issue when I run test suit on intelliJIDEA.

Error details are:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   firefox.exe
Application Version:    39.0.0.5659
Application Timestamp:  55933a80
Fault Module Name:  xul.dll
Fault Module Version:   39.0.0.5659
Fault Module Timestamp: 55934bcf
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   001e39c7
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Firefox version 39 and selenium version 2.45

I tried mvn clean install for my project but firfox always crashes when running tests locally.

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Firefox has stopped working' when running Selenium script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835639/firefox-has-stopped-working-when-running-selenium-script)

Answer (score 0):

According to information you provided it is [security issue](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409), **Windows 7** complaining, wild guess there is some kind of pop-up which is blocking further interaction.

Try to update **Selenium** to the latest version which is [2.47.1](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), see if it helps.

If it was working on previous version of the **Firefox**, then try [downgrade browser](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/).

Answer (score 0):

*Follow the below steps to disable popup and error reporting. This will help the selenium tests to proceed further.*

Steps to disable Mozilla crash popup

**1.1   Turn Off Error Dialog through Group Policy Editor**

1. Open the Group Policy Editor by typing gpedit.msc into the Start search box or the Run dialog.
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Error Reporting. Double click on “Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors” in the pane on the right.
   [image]
3. Click on the radio button Enabled and then press OK. 
   [image]
   **1.2   Turn Off Error Dialog via Registry**
4. Open the Registry Editor by typing regedit into the Start search box or the Win+R Run dialog.
5. Navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting

3. Double click the DontShowUI entry on the right and change its value to 1, then close the registry editor.
   [image]
   **1.3   Disabling Windows Error Reporting**
4. Go to Control Panel > Action Center > Change Action Center settings (top left) > Problem reporting settings.
   [image]
5. Select “Never check for solutions” and click OK. Ask before checking also works because the dialog won’t appear to ask you.