# 'Firefox has stopped working' when running Selenium script

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I run my script on Firefox, my browser shows the dialog below that Firefox has stopped working. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Check you `Firefox` version... if it is `47` you should use `MarionetteDriver` by follow this link... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Comment: Thanks for Help, I uninstalled 47 version and installed 46 version Mozilla Firefox...

Comment: Please look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974061/firefox-has-stopped-working-for-selenium-2-45/47927380#47927380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Check the version of your firefox browser and your selenium version. Selenium does not support firefox browser above version 46. I think your browser might be autoupdated to 47.

Comment: you can make autoupdates off and reinstall the browser again to work on firefox 46. Another option is using MarionetteDriver to work with 47. I suggest to install 46 and continue your work because you may already completed some scripts.

Comment: Yes dear , last ,month i have completed all script but some scripts are left now.

Comment: What is ur browser version now?

Comment: Thanks Sai for your help, i again installed version 46 Mozila Firefox ..

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your firefox browser and your selenium version. Selenium does not support firefox browser above version 46. I think your browser might be autoupdated to 47.  firefox version 46.01 will support.